# Kafka Streams Rocksdb retention didn't remove old data with windowed function

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, rocksdb

I'm running a Kafka streams app with windowed function. But after 24 hours running, local disc usage increased from 5G to 20G and keeps increasing. From what I googled, once I introduced `windowedBy`, it should remove old data automatically.

My topology looks like below:

```
stream.selectKey(selectKey A)
.groupByKey(..)
.windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofMinutes(60)).grace(Duration.ZERO))
.reduce((value1,value2) -> value2)
.suppress.toStreams()
.selectKey(selectKey B).mapValues().filter()
.groupByKey().reduce.toStream().to()
```

One thing I can't understand is, from this topology, it will create two internal repartition topics, as `repartition-03` and `repartition-14` for two `groupBy` actions. From the disc, all machines which are taking `repartition-03` tasks are having high disc usage and seems never removing old data while machines which are running `repartition-14` tasks are always under low disc usage.

When I log in to the machines, I found different path for those two machines as below:

```
/tmp/kafka-streams/test-group/2_40/rocksdb/KSTREAM-REDUCE-STATE-STORE-0000000014
```

```
/tmp/kafka-streams/test-group/1_4/KSTREAM-REDUCE-STATE-STORE-0000000003/KSTREAM-REDUCE-STATE-STORE-0000000003.1568808000000
```

Why they are having different path? `2_40` is for the `repartition-14` tasks and it has `rocksdb` in the path while the other doesn't contain `rocksdb`. Meanwhile, taks `1_4` keeps couple folders like `KSTREAM-REDUCE-STATE-STORE-0000000003.1568808000000` but with different suffix.

I though once I introduced windowedBy function, rocksdb will remove old data when window is expired? And why above two internal repartition topics have different path and retention behavior?

Any help is highly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Default retention period is 24h. You can reduce it via

```java
.reduce(..., Materialized.with(...).withRetention(...));
```

Comment: Hi Matthias, what is `Materialized.as(null)`? Could you explain more about it? It doesn't allow me to put `null` as parameters here. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry. My bad. I thought that would work -- updated my answer. Try `with(...)` instead of `as(...)`.

Comment: An updates on `Materialized.withRetention`, seems like KStreams provides config `WINDOW_STORE_CHANGE_LOG_ADDITIONAL_RETENTION_MS_CONFIG` to override the default value 24HR. Not sure if it's the same as `Materialized.withRetention`

Comment: `withRetention` sets the store retention time, and that retention time is also use for the underlying changelog topic. The config parameter `WINDOW_STORE_CHANGE_LOG_ADDITIONAL_RETENTION_MS_CONFIG` is only applied to the changelog topic and it's added to the retention time.